# Really confused about orbital science

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, definition, escape-velocity

Okay let’s start straight away, **What is [Escape Velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity)?**

1. Is it the speed required to get into orbit, or
2. is it the speed required to escape the SOI (Sphere of Influence) of Earth completely?

If it’s the (1) then probably Google is wrong and probably everything else like the **ISS** is also wrong because according to them, we need to have just 6.11 Km/S of speed to get into orbit.

If it’s (2) then... I don't know. **Is it?**

Comment: Escape velocity isn't 6.11 km/s.

Comment: The most common definition of escape velocity is: the minimum speed needed so that an object will not return.  Equivalently, the initial speed at which the speed an infinite distance away is zero.  That's neither (1) nor (2).

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity ?

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient i AGREE

Comment: @garypi really like the way you explained , can you go a little deeper and elaborate

Comment: Why don't you try to calculate it yourself and see if you can understand it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape velocity is the speed required to escape to infinity ballistically from the surface of a planet (or from a point in space) neglecting atmospheric drag.

From the surface of the earth, escape velocity is about $11.2$ km/s.

The speed required to maintain a circular orbit about a planet is smaller than escape velocity. The [ISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station), for example, has an orbital speed of $7.66$ km/s.

A satellite in a circular orbit would have to increase its speed by a factor of $\sqrt 2 \approx 1.4$ (or, in other words, double its kinetic energy) to reach escape velocity.